# Loading JFrame blank when thread processing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to show a "Please wait" JFrame while my program copies some files.
Context : I have a first JFrame that allows a user to pick files and then clicks on a button to trigger the copy. This is when I want to display the "Please wait" JFrame and make it disappears when everything is done.
I have succeeded to make this JFrame appeared and disappeared but it is always blank.
The code for the "Please Wait" JFrame :

```
public class Loader implements Runnable {

    JFrame loadingFrame = new JFrame();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Parameters for size and position
        loadingFrame.setSize(180,100);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JLabel("Please wait ...", SwingConstants.CENTER), "Center");
        loadingFrame.add(panel);
        loadingFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        loadingFrame.setVisible(true);
        //((JComponent) loadingFrame.getContentPane()).revalidate();
        //loadingFrame.repaint();
    }

    public void destroy() {     
        loadingFrame.setVisible(false);
        loadingFrame.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Loader());
    }

}
```

As you can see, I tried "repaint()" and "revalidate()" but it didn't work.
I call the Loader class in this function :

```
public void analyzeAndCopy(){       
        // Show loading Frame
        Loader loader = new Loader();
        loader.run();

        [... copy code...]


        // Hide loading Frame
        loader.destroy();
    }
```

The Please Wait JFrame appears blank, and stays (as wanted) while files are being copied and disappears after, but it stays blank all the way. :/

I think it may be related to Thread, I tried to create a 2nd thread to call the JFrame, it didn't work. I'm running out of ideas...

Any help will be much appreciated ! :)

Thanks

Comment: You appear to be violating the single threaded nature of Swing, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. You seem to be "loading" something from within the context of the EDT which is taking time, which is the reason why your frame isn't be updated.  Have a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
loader.run();
```

with

```
 new Thread(loader).start();
```

and add a line to method run:

```
 loadingFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

and you can use JDialog instead of JFrame

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately it didn't change anything the JFrame or JDialog appears but still blank.

Comment: depends on files selected, between 10 seconds and 5 minutes

Comment: by replacing  [... copy code...]  with Thread.sleep(1000); everything work fine!!

Comment: I agree when I put this in a "test.java" and just called the loader it works.
But when I replace all my copy code by Thread.sleep(1000) it is still blank.
Maybe it is because the function is called inside a Listener of a button which is on a JFrame ... i don't know :(
The weird thing is if I delete "loader.destroy()" the label "Please Wait" appears but only at the end of the execution...

Comment: Don't ever call sleep from the event thread. What you want is a modal dialog with DO_NOTHIN_ON_CLOSE as its default close operation. Then you run the loader operation in a separate thread, and when it is done it calls` dialog.setVisible(false)` in another invokeLater runnable.

Comment: Your violating the single threaded nature of Swing by doing this